# Exporting Excel files in R based on Categories in a Column

Tags: r

I want to export multiple excel data files for a single data frame for each category in a specific column. For example, I've 50 student scores from five states. How can I export each state student scores in separate excel file. Furthermore, when I export KS student scores in a separate excel file, I want R to save the name of the file with the state name (i.e. KS.xlsx). (I'd like to use 'excel_xlsx' from 'openxlsx' library if possible.

Here is simulated data for explanation:

```
states = rep(c("AR", "KS", "CA", "MO", "NE"),times = c(10, 5, 15, 8, 12))
scores = rnorm(50, mean=30, sd=5)
dat = data.frame(states, scores)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data based on state and use `Map` to write separate excel files.

```
list_data <- split(dat, dat$states)
Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, list_data, paste0(names(list_data), '.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by first splitting your df according to `states` using `split` and second by using e.g. `purrr::imap` to save the splitted dfs in separate files like so:

```
library(openxlsx)

states = rep(c("AR", "KS", "CA", "MO", "NE"),times = c(10, 5, 15, 8, 12))
scores = rnorm(50, mean=30, sd=5)
dat = data.frame(states, scores)

dat_split <- split(dat, dat$states)

purrr::imap(dat_split, ~ write.xlsx(.x, paste0(.y, ".xlsx")))
```